# MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v6.4.1) Crashes in SFMCNetworkRequest

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios, mobilepush-ios, push

Getting a fair amount of crashes from v6.4.1 of the MarketingCloudSDK via our third party crash reporter Crashlytics.

On the order of a few hundred since this was released. All the effected users are on iOS 13.

```
SFMCNetworkRequest.m line 179
-[SFMCNetworkRequest dataTask] 
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
Task created in a session that has been invalidated
```

Stack Trace:

```
3  client 0x105ae92c8 -[SFMCNetworkRequest dataTask] + 179 (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:179)    
4  client 0x105ae9734 -[SFMCNetworkRequest performRequestWithCompletionHandler:requestCompletionHandler:] + 238 (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:238)
5  client 0x105acbbdc -[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation sendRegistration:] + 734 (MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m:734)
6  client 0x105acb0cc __47-[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation sendRegistration]_block_invoke + 664 (MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m:664)
7  client 0x105ae7908 __83+[SFMCTimedDispatcher dispatchWithIdentifier:onQueue:afterTimeInterval:completion:]_block_invoke + 60 (SFMCTimedDispatcher.m:60
```

Any thoughts to what could be causing this? Or if a fix is in progress?

I can send more data in if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This crash was a known issue that should have been fixed with the 6.4.1 release. I just looked at your stacktrace, and matched up the line numbers with our code. Those line numbers do not look to match our 6.4.1 release, but they do match our 6.3.6 release. Can you confirm that you are seeing this crash with our 6.4.1 release and not previous releases? If so, could you send another crash report making sure it is from 6.4.1?

Comment: You are correct, I was on the wrong branch which was updated but not in Production. We are behind on Production, so I'll update now. Thanks!