# MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v7.2.1) Crashes in SFMCNetworkRequest

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, ios, mobilepush-ios

Getting a fair amount of crashes from v7.2.1 of the MarketingCloudSDK via our third party crash reporter Crashlytics.

Probably had about 20 crashes since we upgraded to v7.X.X. Most of the effected users are on iOS 13, 7% are on iOS 12.

```
SFMCNetworkRequest.m line 181
-[SFMCNetworkRequest dataTask] 
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
Task created in a session that has been invalidated
```

Stack Trace:

```
3  client                         0x1050371e0 -[SFMCNetworkRequest dataTask] + 181 (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:181)
4  client                         0x105037774 -[SFMCNetworkRequest performRequestWithCompletionHandler:requestCompletionHandler:] + 259 (SFMCNetworkRequest.m:259)
5  client                         0x105051cbc -[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence sendETAnalytics]
6  client                         0x10504fd70 __50-[MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence sendAllAnalytics:]_block_invoke
7  client                         0x10502cfcc __83+[SFMCTimedDispatcher dispatchWithIdentifier:onQueue:afterTimeInterval:completion:]_block_invoke + 60 (SFMCTimedDispatcher.m:60)
```

[We've had this error before back in the v6.X.X versions and was told it was fixed,](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288802/marketingcloudsdk-ios-v6-4-1-crashes-in-sfmcnetworkrequest) but it's back again.

I can send more data in if needed.

Comment: Please open a support request through your account representative.

Comment: @BillMote I was told that this is where we are supposed to open support tickets, is this no longer the case?

Comment: SMH ... StackOverflow should _never_ be recommended as _the_ source for support.  You should open a support case through your account representative and they can escalate to our team if the success engineers cannot resolve your problem.